# Caching an React/Meteor webpage

Tags: reactjs, meteor, service-worker

I want to speed up the initial load of an React/Meteor web page. 
One of several Ideas is to cache data. So fare so good...
This was tried with service workers. This was only possible for me under "/public/" folder but in addition I want to cache data from eg. "/client/" for caching more data.
Is this possible to cache more data from other folders?

I did pretty much the same as described here under "Step 1 - Add a service worker ":
https://dev.to/jankapunkt/transform-any-meteor-app-into-a-pwa-4k44

**UPDATES:**
we are using this Web page only in an intranet without internet connection.

Comment: What's the error? what doesn't work right?

Comment: I want to cache not only the "/public/" folder. caching public worked  how to cache other folders? 
For other files from other folders I get in Chrome-Develper-Tools "Content-Length" = 0. (I guess it means the file length in bytes.) But I do not get a real error message.

Answer (score 0):

things with React and Meteor don't really work that way.
It is expected to have an up to 1MB JS bundle to deliver to your client. A medium size app should look at 400-500kb of gzipped bundle size.

Don't use the public folder for assets, put everything in a CDN with edge cacheing like the AWS Cloudfront (store in S3 and expose via Cloudfront), or any other storage.
In your CDN you can set the expiry and cache-control (max-age) and this is used by the client (browser) for cacheing assets.
Deliver your JS and CSS bundles from a CDN.
Use split code extensively (ideally at routing level).
Whenever possible use async libraries form maps, players etc instead of NPM (which builds into your bundle).
With a PWA environment you will cache your bundle files not your public folder. The tutorial you followed for PWA is incomplete and useless. It only looks to how to get a green badge in the audit, it does nothing of any use.

One more thing, your Meteor bundle size impacts the traffic on your Meteor server. This is why you better deliver the bundle and all assets from CDN's.
Cacheing more with service workers only leads to flickers, inconsistencies between tabs and browsers, errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
We are using this Web page only in an intranet without internet connection.
- Sorry for not telling this.

Comment: This opens another question: is your intranet a LAN or it goes VPN over internet? If you have this problem in a LAN (at +100Mbps per connection) then something is definitely wrong. If you see this in remote locations (like other offices in other countries), you could consider an Electron client or Cordova desktop or ... I will help you with a proper PWA configuration to pick up the files that you need .... having in mind the things mentioned above.